# JavaScript or jQuery Sliding Control

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

This is not a question about sliding panels. This is a question about sliding controls that control values.

```
       Could anyone provide me with a couple of links
       to web pages where nice-looking sliding controls
       are used?
```

Say on an order page (you slide the quantity of items and the grand total gets immediately updated) or on a configuration page (for CPU, RAM, Storage and so forth)?

For the life of me, I cannot find the examples I've looked at a couple of months ago.

Yes, I know, the jQuery UI Slider can be styled, and I've been looking at a bunch of those examples, I even Google'd around for half a morning and searched for all kinds of things...but no luck.

All I want to see are some elegant solutions others have come up with, and see what is possible. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

it's been a while since the question was asked but anyway, here is the link http://egorkhmelev.github.com/jslider/ - jQuery Slider plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use http://jqueryui.com/ and create a custom theme to the slider or custom yourself the css in order to add images or other effects.